# Launchpad Search Field not working - cannot type

Tags: launchpad

The launchpad search field suddenly no longer accepts text input for me.

[image]

Any idea how to get this to accept text again?  Searching for an app was so very useful.

Answer (score 51):

Hit the tab key a few times. Worked for me.

You need to hit Tab once the launchpad screen comes up. The tab will then put focus on the search bar, and then pressing it again will remove it. Pressing it ~20times seems to cause some sort of reset. Once you visibly notice the cursor, things should be good.

Other things to try:

- terminal > `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`
- logout / login
- restart

Comment: While this does bring focus back to the search box, there clearly seems to be some type of issue with initial focus on this control. I hope this is addressed with an update.

Comment: Wow. I pressed the tab like twenty times and it actually finally started working. Weeeeird.

Comment: +1. Actually need to do this around 20 times to see an effect.

Comment: This issue is ridiculous, but the fix works!

Comment: +1 Incredible, the tabbing 20 times actually works!!! Thanks. Wow, how random!

Comment: two years later and this is *still* an issue.  good job with the bug fixing, apple.

Comment: and yeah, 20ish tabs later and input works.  thx!

Comment: I found this to work as well: tapping tab 20 times in the search field

Comment: I had to do more like 30. I wonder if it is related to the number of icons that launchpad is managing. On MacOS Sierra, the *Search* bar seems to go in and out of focus (the word `Search` shifts from centered to left-justified within the box) many many times during the tabbing, but eventually the keyboard caret becomes visible. Crazy.

Comment: I have 4 screens of icons, so around 140 in total.  Tried pressing tab key 200 times and still can't get search to work.  Even when I click with the mouse in the search box, the input box will not respond to the text I type.  Very frustrating.  There doesn't seem to be any fix to this on discussions.apple.com either...  I'm using Sierra, if that makes any difference?

Comment: Apple support suggested a restart, that seems to fix it for now, hopefully it will be a permanent fix!

Comment: I have 2 screens - solution of 20+ tabs didn't work on first screen but did on second screen. Seen this issue on 2 separate Macs running Sierra (10.5 and 10.4 or 10.3), each on one occasion. Good to find this solution, thank you.

Comment: This answer did not work for me specifically.
I pressed Tab fifty times, no result.
Then tried Shift+Tab roughly 5 times and my cursor appeared. Why???, I do not know why. But I think it is apparent here that no one knows "Why?" OSX Ver.: Sierra 10.12.6
Hardware: Mid 2012

Comment: 3 years later, OS X 10.13 — STILL an issue (and the answer still helps)

Comment: That terminal snippet just helped me in 2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Hit the tab key until a cursor shows up in the search bar at the top of the launchpad view.  As mentioned in some of the comments, you could have to hit it 20 times or more.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today. On the Apple forums, I found a tip to delete the contents of `~/Library/Application Support/Dock` and to restart the Dock using `killall Dock` afterwards. This causes Launchpad to rebuild its database and supposedly should reactivate the search field.

I tried this and it did not work for me initially.

Meanwhile, I applied another tip, namely to repair the disk permissions with the disk tool (and then forgot about the topic).

A couple of hours later (now) - when I was looking for alternative solutions on Ask Different - I was suddenly able to search again in Launchpad.

So I expect, that either one of the tips or both in combination did the trick.

Comment: This did work for me, but it is another work around. If it is a bug with focus in the OS control, I hope it is addressed soon.

Answer (score 1):

Merely rebooting the laptop did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This ALSO works when you can't rename a grouped folder on the launch pad. *ie: drag two apps on the launchpad together and create a group, then open it, click the name and try to rename it.* - I had to hit the tab key like 50 times.

This issue goes back many years, and isn't just OS Sierra. So whatever is around after Sierra, try this first before deleting files, messing with file permissions, or completely resetting Launchpad. This method, you don't have to logout. I have tons of stuff open all the time, and hate logging out. It's a preparation process.

**So tap the `tab` button anywhere from 20 to 50 times.** It's worth a shot before doing anything else :)

Answer (score -1):

In the Launchpad, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>. The pad will fade and zoom, and when you hit it again it works so you can type again.

Answer (score -1):

Tab 20 times or so worked for me.

Comment: Please explain more about how tabbing 20 times will allow this to work?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how tabbing 20 or so times will address this issue. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.